# python 3 behave webdriver - OOP passing Driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

So I have been trying to make my project more OOP but am having great difficulty getting the driver to pass between the python files.

```
TestAutomation/
    Features/
        somefeature.feature
    Objects/
        main_misc.py
    Steps/
        actionwords.py
        steps.py
    Tools/
        AutoTools.py
    environment.py
```

environment.py

```
class DriverSetup:
    def get_driver():
        ...
        return webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)

def before_all(context):
        driver = DriverSetup.get_driver()
        context.actionwords = Actionwords()
        base_url = ''
        driver.get(base_url)
        AutoTools.Navigation.wait_for_page_to_load(driver)
```

AutoTools.py

```
class Navigation:
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver

    @staticmethod
    def wait_for_page_to_load(self):
        old_page = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
```

I only gave enough where it gets the error, it will hit the step. In Debug Self has with curent_url with the proper url in place even has a window handle
When I step into, it goes back to environment.py to run hook exception - 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: What is the `TestAutomation` line? Is it meant to be a command? If so, why are there single, double and triple dashes?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're accessing the `driver` attribute of `self` when you call the `wait_for_page_to_load(self)` method. That is, when you're passing in the Firefox webdriver to the method, `self` is referring to the Firefox webdriver, so it's trying to access the Firefox webdriver's `driver` attribute, which is incorrect.

What you need to do is instantiate a `Navigation` object so that `self` is referring to said object and `self.driver` is referring to the Firefox driver you're passing in. From your code, I'd expect something like this:

```
def before_all(context):
    # These 4 lines are independent of the Navigation class
    driver = DriverSetup.get_driver()
    context.actionwords = Actionwords()
    base_url = ''
    driver.get(base_url)

    # These 2 lines are dependent on the Navigation class
    # On the right, the Navigation object is instantiated
    # On the left, the object is initialized to the navigation_driver variable
    navigation_driver = AutoTools.Navigation(driver)

    # After, you can call your method since the object's self.driver
    # was instantiated in the previous line and properly refers to the Firefox webdriver
    navigation_driver.wait_for_page_to_load()
```